# Show modal not more than once for all use cases

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a script which depending on the use case fires a modal over the website. The use cases are:

- Longer than x second on page
- When scroll 200px from bottom
- when leaving the window on top of the page

The modal window (with Bootstrap) is only showed once for all use cases and site-wide, so if I am "Longer than x seconds on page" and modal is triggered and I close it, it should never appear again. However "when scroll 200px from bottom" on the same page the modal appears again, which is not OK. What is working is that when you go to another page of the website and had the modal seen, it won't show any more due to the local storage file returning 'true'.

is there any way to continuously check if the local storage is 'true' and then not fire the modal anymore rather than on initial page load?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2wu6qu5e/3/embedded/result/
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2wu6qu5e/3/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    if (localStorage.getItem('test') == null) {
    // show  after 10 seconds
    setTimeout( function(){ 
        $('#form').modal('show');
          localStorage.setItem('test', true)
    }, 10000 );



    //show when scroll 200 pixels from bottom
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
    $('#form').modal('show');
    localStorage.setItem('test', true)
  }
});

    //show when mouse leave on top of page (url bar)
    $(document).on('mouseleave', leaveFromTop);
        function leaveFromTop(e){
           localStorage.setItem('test', true)
           if( e.clientY < 0 ) {
                 $('#form').modal('show');
            }
    } // end if statement

});
```

Comment: If anyone is ever looking for a workaround, this works:

      $(".modal-body button, .modal-backdrop").click(function() {
        $(".modal").remove();
        $("body").removeClass("modal-open")
      });

Answer (score 1):

Following works as a workaround:

```
  $(".modal-body button, .modal-backdrop").click(function() {
    $(".modal").remove();
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open")
  });
```